# Javascript not working in IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am currently creating a website and have some javascript that works in all browsers except IE7 and IE8. I have done some tests on the code by inserting several 'alert' statements and deduced that the javascript breaks at one particular 'if' statement. It is not the code within the 'if' statement either because I have also tested this.

I can't see anything wrong with the actual 'if' statement myself but please let me know if there is a problem with IE7/IE8 and the code I have produced. The code can be seen below.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
var Items = new Array("a","b","c","d");
var queryString = window.location.search.substring(1);

if(Items.indexOf(queryString) != "-1"){
    //code goes here
}
```

Comment: indexOf() return int not string.

if(Items.indexOf(queryString) != -1){ // would work.
}

Comment: Javascript certainly does work in those two browsers.  indexOf is not a method of an array in all browser though.  You can extend the array prototype to add this functionality if you require it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no "indexOf()" function on IE's Array prototype. If there were, it'd return a numeric value and not a string.

You can find an "indexOf()" polyfill at the [MDN documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for the function.

Also, when you declare and initialize arrays, use array constant notation:

```
var Items = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
```

Comment: That's great thanks, I actually just solved it by writing my own 'for' loop, a few more lines of code but now works perfectly in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of extending the Array object to support indexOf in those browsers that don't support it.  Doing this has its own issues, if you ever iterate an array via for (x in a) (not suggested) and don't check hasOwnProperty this will cause you problems.

```
if(!Array.indexOf){
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj){
        for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){
            if(this[i]==obj){
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```